# Multiple commands within Supervisor - Python/Linux

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, supervisord

I'm using the amazing utility `supervisord`

---

I'm happily running a few apps editing the config file as follows:

```
[program: Django Dev Server]
command=python /path/to/project/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000

[program: MongoDB]
command=sudo /path/to/mongod
```

---

**Now problem is that some apps need a few commands before they start up in order to prepare them for startup.**

e.g. verifying conditions, cleaning folders, etc...

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of calling `manage.py`, write a script (call it, say, `start_manage.py`) which verifies conditions, cleans folders, etc, and then calls `manage.py` (using `subprocess.Popen`). Or, of course, `start_manage` could be a shell script if that fits your needs better.

Then change the config file to run

```
command=python start_manage.py
```